# Prioritize some workflow executions over others

Tags: amazon-web-services, workflow, priority-queue, amazon-swf

I've been using the flow framework for amazon swf and I want to be able to run priority workflow executions and normal workflow executions. If there are priority tasks, then activities should pick up the priority tasks ahead of normal priority tasks. What is the best way to accomplish this?

I'm thinking that the following might work but I wonder if there's a better/recommended approach.

1. I'll define two Activity Workers and two activity lists for the activity. One priority list and one normal list. Each worker will be using the same activity class.
2. Both workers will be run on the same host (ec2 instance).
3. On the workflow, I'll define two methods: startNormalWorkflow and startHighWorkflow. In the startHighWorkflow method, I can use ActivitySchedulingOptions to put the task on the high priority list.

Problem with this approach is that there is no guarantee that the high priority task is scheduled before normal tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good question, it had me scratching my head for a while.

Of course, there is more than one way to skin this cat and there exists a number of valid solutions. I focused here on the simplest possible that I could conceive of, namely, execution of tasks in order of priority within a single workflow.

The scenario goes as follows: I define one activity worker serving two task lists, `default_tasks` and `urgent_tasks`, with a trivial logic:

1. If there are pending tasks on the `urgent_tasks` list, then pick one from there,
2. Otherwise, pick a task from `default_tasks`
3. Execute any task selected.

The question is how to check if any high priority tasks are pending? [CountPendingActivityTasks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_CountPendingActivityTasks.html) API comes to the rescue!

I know you use [Flow](http://aws.amazon.com/swf/flow/) for development. My example is written using `boto.swf.layer2` as Python is so much easier for prototyping - but the idea remains the same and can be extended to a more complex scenario with high and low priority workflow executions.

So, to accomplish the above using [boto.swf](https://github.com/boto/boto) follow these steps:

**Export credentials to the environment**

```
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your access key
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= your secret key
```

**Get the code snippets**

For convenience, you can fork it from github:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:oozie/stackoverflow.git
$ cd stackoverflow/amazon-swf/priority_tasks/
```

To bootstrap the domain and the workflow:

```
# domain_setup.py 
import boto.swf.layer2 as swf

DOMAIN = 'stackoverflow'
VERSION = '1.0'

swf.Domain(name=DOMAIN).register()
swf.ActivityType(domain=DOMAIN, name='SomeActivity', version=VERSION, task_list='default_tasks').register()
swf.WorkflowType(domain=DOMAIN, name='MyWorkflow', version=VERSION, task_list='default_tasks').register()
```

Decider implementation:

```
# decider.py
import boto.swf.layer2 as swf

DOMAIN = 'stackoverflow'
ACTIVITY = 'SomeActivity'
VERSION = '1.0'

class MyWorkflowDecider(swf.Decider):

    domain = DOMAIN
    task_list = 'default_tasks'
    version = VERSION

    def run(self):
        history = self.poll()
        print history
        if 'events' in history:
            # Get a list of non-decision events to see what event came in last.
            workflow_events = [e for e in history['events']
                               if not e['eventType'].startswith('Decision')]

            decisions = swf.Layer1Decisions()

            last_event = workflow_events[-1]
            last_event_type = last_event['eventType']

            if last_event_type == 'WorkflowExecutionStarted':
                # At the start, get the worker to fetch the first assignment.
                decisions.schedule_activity_task(ACTIVITY+'1', ACTIVITY, VERSION, task_list='default_tasks')
                decisions.schedule_activity_task(ACTIVITY+'2', ACTIVITY, VERSION, task_list='urgent_tasks')
                decisions.schedule_activity_task(ACTIVITY+'3', ACTIVITY, VERSION, task_list='default_tasks')
                decisions.schedule_activity_task(ACTIVITY+'4', ACTIVITY, VERSION, task_list='urgent_tasks')
                decisions.schedule_activity_task(ACTIVITY+'5', ACTIVITY, VERSION, task_list='default_tasks')
            elif last_event_type == 'ActivityTaskCompleted':
                # Complete workflow execution after 5 completed activities.
                closed_activity_count = sum(1 for wf_event in workflow_events if wf_event.get('eventType') == 'ActivityTaskCompleted')
                if closed_activity_count == 5:
                    decisions.complete_workflow_execution()

            self.complete(decisions=decisions)
            return True
```

Prioritizing worker implementation:

```
# worker.py
import boto.swf.layer2 as swf

DOMAIN = 'stackoverflow'
VERSION = '1.0'

class PrioritizingWorker(swf.ActivityWorker):

    domain = DOMAIN
    version = VERSION

    def run(self):

        urgent_task_count = swf.Domain(name=DOMAIN).count_pending_activity_tasks('urgent_tasks').get('count', 0)
        if urgent_task_count > 0:
            self.task_list = 'urgent_tasks'
        else:
            self.task_list = 'default_tasks'
        activity_task = self.poll()

        if 'activityId' in activity_task:
            print urgent_task_count, 'urgent tasks in the queue. Executing ' + activity_task.get('activityId')
            self.complete()
            return True
```

**Run the workflow from three instances of an interactive Python shell**

Run the decider:

```
$ python -i decider.py
>>> while MyWorkflowDecider().run(): pass
...
```

Start an execution:

```
$ python -i decider.py 
>>> swf.WorkflowType(domain='stackoverflow', name='MyWorkflow', version='1.0', task_list='default_tasks').start()
```

Finally, kick off the worker and watch the tasks as they're getting executed:

```
$ python -i worker.py 
>>> while PrioritizingWorker().run(): pass
... 
2 urgent tasks in the queue. Executing SomeActivity2
1 urgent tasks in the queue. Executing SomeActivity4
0 urgent tasks in the queue. Executing SomeActivity5
0 urgent tasks in the queue. Executing SomeActivity1
0 urgent tasks in the queue. Executing SomeActivity3
```

Comment: thank you for such a detailed response. We decided to have the workers on separate instances such that we can autoscale them independently

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that using a separate task list that you have to check first doesn't work well.

There's a couple of problems.

First, the count API doesn't update reliably. So you may get 0 tasks even when there are urgent tasks in the queue.

Second, the call that polls for tasks hangs if there are no tasks available. So when you poll for the non-urgent tasks, that will "stick" for either 2 minutes, or until you have a non-urgent task to do.

So this can cause all kinds of problems in your workflow.

For this to work, SWF would have to implement a polling API that could return the first task from a list of task lists. Then it would be much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The first point seems like a problem with the service that should be corrected. Amazon folks are great about responding to user reports, I recommend getting in touch with them, e.g. through an AWS forum. On the second point - you're right - the example above is oversimplified for purposes of explanation. It should be possible to reduce this delay by also testing 'default_tasks` for outstanding `count_pending_activity_tasks`.